# How to do backward relationships lookup for all model objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to have a list view of all products from `Product` model with their own image URLs from `ProductImage` model. Each product may have multiple images.

#### models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):  
   product_id = models.CharField(max_length=6)  
   material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)  
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   enabled = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Active')  

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

clsas ProductImage(models.Model):  
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   url = models.URLField(max_length=250)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   enabled = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Active')

   def __str__(self):
      return self.url
```

I've been trying to implement the queries from this Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward). But the example specifically target an object by its `id`. How to do the same thing with all objects?

> `b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)`
>   `b.entry_set.all()` # Returns all Entry objects related to Blog.

Is it possible to do it without changing the Foreign Key relation into
`productimage = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImage)` in `Product` model ?

My current attempt on `views.py`:

```
def product_list_view(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    images = products.productimage_set.all()

    context = {
        'product_list': products,
        'product_image_list': images
    }
    return render(request, 'product_visualizers/product_list.html', context)
```

#### product_list.html template:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    <li>
         <p> {{ product.product_id }}: </p>
             {{ product.name }} - {{ product.material }} - {{ product.created_at }} - {{ product.enabled }}
         <p> {{ product_image_list.url }} </p>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I got:
`AttributeError at /product_visualizers/product/
...
...
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'productimage_set'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the **double for loop** with **children_set** property:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    <li>
         <p> {{ product.product_id }}: </p>
             {{ product.name }} - {{ product.material }} - {{ product.created_at }} - {{ product.enabled }}

             {% for image in product.productimage_set.all %}
                 <img src="{{image.url}}" /> 
             {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, Astik. Thank you for answering my qustion. I think you misplaced `{% endif %}` with `{% endfor %}` to close the if statement. And I got new error that said: `'RelatedManager' object is not iterable` that points to `{% if product.productimage_set %}`.

Comment: With your answer I assume I should remove the `images` variable and `'product_image_list'` context in my `views.py`, right?

Comment: @Nathan, Yeah I had mistyped that endfor which I edited and yeah you no longer need product_image_list now.

Comment: I've edited my `views.py` but still got error: `'RelatedManager' object is not iterable` that points to `{% if product.productimage_set %}` in the template.

Comment: @Nathan, Check the updated answer once and let me know. I had missed the `.all` property.

Comment: Thank you, Astik. Now it perfectly works just as what I needed. I want to upvote your answer but don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Ok, now you can upvote. Thanks for letting me know that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Select_related' to fetch all the records,

Example :

```
productimage.objects.all().select_related('product')
```

The above query will give you all the records join with product model, and in your template you can use display the values as you wish

Comment: In my `views.py` I assign `productimage.objects.all().select_related('product')` to `context['product_image_list']`. In my template I tried to display it as `{{ product_image_list }}`. The result is in <QuerySet> and show all product images instead of corresponding images for each product.
What should I code in my template to fix this?